# How can I add a custom emoji to the already existing emojis (ore replace one)

Tags: linux, emoji

Hello I'm starting to play with the linux console apearance and I would like to customize the @ emoji, I know I can do it in many ways, I used `sudo nano ~/.zshrc` and modified a few lines so i can replace it with `☠` (usual when going root in kali) or `㉿` (base in kali)

my question here is to know if there is a way to add custom emojis to the emoji base software integrated in latest versions of linux

if not can I create custom unicode emoji

it's doesn't change anything but i'm on latest version of kali (you guessed)

Comment: the `@` is not an emoji

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.